# Adding nodes by value

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to add nodes in a sorted manner to my linked list. My code just keeps adding to the end if the value is less than the end of the linked list. I am not sure how to fix this or if I am not fully checking for the right scenario.

I have tried to increment current until it is greater than the nodeToAdd to place the node between, but it always just places it at the end.

```
        public void AddOrdered(int value)
    {
        LinkedListNode nodeToAdd = new LinkedListNode(value);
        LinkedListNode cur = m_first;
        if (m_first == null) 
            m_first = nodeToAdd;//new LinkedListNode(value);

        else if (nodeToAdd.m_data < m_first.m_data) 
        {
            AddAtFront(value);
        }
        else if (nodeToAdd.m_data < cur.m_next.m_data) 
        {
            LinkedListNode temp = new LinkedListNode(value);
            temp = m_first.m_next;
            m_first.m_next = nodeToAdd;
            nodeToAdd.m_next = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            AddAtEnd(value);
        }
    }
```

supplement add at end/front methods--which are working fine

```
        public void AddAtEnd(int value)
    {
        LinkedListNode cur = m_first;
        if (m_first == null)
        {
            LinkedListNode lnl = new LinkedListNode(value);
            m_first = lnl;
        }
        while (cur.m_next != null)
        {
            cur = cur.m_next;
        }
        cur.m_next = new LinkedListNode(value);
    }

        public void AddAtFront(int value)
    {
        if (m_first == null) 
        {
            LinkedListNode ln = new LinkedListNode(value);
            m_first = ln;
        }
        else
        {
            LinkedListNode lnl = new LinkedListNode(value); 
            lnl.m_next = m_first;                           
            m_first = lnl;                                 
        }
    }
```

The values should get added in order but the output is placing them at the very end of the linked list unless new min/maxs are entered as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I am assuming that m_first is your first node. With this as an assumption the code would be as follows:

```
public void AddOrdered(int value)
    {
        LinkedListNode nodeToAdd = new LinkedListNode(value);
        LinkedListNode cur;
        if (m_first == null || m_first.data >= nodeToAdd.data)
        {
            nodeToAdd.next = m_first;
            m_first = nodeToAdd;
        }
        else
        {
            cur = m_first;
            while (cur.next != null &&
            cur.next.data < nodeToAdd.data)
                cur = cur.next;

            nodeToAdd.next = cur.next;
            cur.next = nodeToAdd;
        }
    }
```